# Passing information to an imported Python module

Tags: python, import, module, initialization

I wish I could get my module to initialize two different ways, based on an option chosen in the main program. Wishful code:

Main program:

```
<magic variable> = True
import mymodule
```

mymodule.py:

```
def start1():
    ...
def start2():
    ...
if <magic variable>: start1()
else: start2()
```

Is there any way to place *magic variable* where the imported module can find it? Without creating yet another module?

Comment: Why can't you use 2 distinct modules, possibly extracting the common bits into something imported by both?

Answer (score 3):

The way I would solve this problem is by creating a common function in your imported module that would be used for initialization. The user would then pass in the flag to choose a certain initialization style:

**mymodule.py**

```
def init(flag=True):
    if flag:
        start1()
    else:
        start2()

def start1():
    print('start1 called')

def start2():
    print('start2 called')
```

**main.py**

```
import mymodule
mymodule.init() # Or False could be passed in, depending on the users choice.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have two ways in one module, you need main program to initialize it

```
<magic variable> = True
import mymodule
if <magic variable>:
    mymodule.start1()
else:
    mymodule.start2()
```